# Keycast alternative in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

Is there any software like [Keycast](https://github.com/cho45/KeyCast) (Mac)?

It shows what keys we have pressed for demonstration purpose.
my requirements

- The keys we pressed should be shown on the top of the screen irrespective of the window we are on
- Able to toggle the app behavior like setting on or off

Comment: Thanks, now it just lacks the price tag :) Must it be free – or how much would you be willing to spend if there is no free app?

Comment: If somebody charges for this kind of app it would be a pretty bad strategy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Screenkey](https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey).

For terminal, you can try showkey but it prints to Standard output only.